# Matlab sin wave plotting

Tags: matlab, plot, trigonometry

I am newbie on matlab sorry if the question is so silly. I search about it but I could not understand the issue clearly.

I want to work with interval int=(-20:20) which has 41 element on sin wave.
when I plot sin(int) it is ploting well but when I try to plot sin(50*int) evenif there must be a lot of change of y value than sin(int) there is not. When I change int=(-100:100) has 201 element, still same wrong plotting. I only take real plot when I change int=(-10:0.1:10) has again 201 element

What is the reason behind?

Comment: Are you aware that the `sin` function takes an argument in radians, not degrees ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing is a signal processing problem called [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions).

Basically, if you don't sample a sine wave often enough, the discretized sine wave can appear to have a lower frequency than the actual continuous wave did:

[image]

To fix this problem you must sample *at least twice as often as the frequency of the signal*. (See [the sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).)

`sin(x)` has a frequency of 1 rad/s so you must sample at least as often as 2 rad/s = 0.318 Hz, or about 1 sample for every 3 units.

`int=(-20:20)` satisfies this requirement with a sampling rate of 1 Hz = 6.28 rad/s > 2 rad/s.

`50*int`, or `-1000:50:1000` does not, as it has a sampling rate of 1/50 Hz = 0.1257 rad/s < 2 rads/s.

Comment: Love that picture. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng I raid wikipedia now and again for my SO answers. ;)

Comment: lmao .  Is that figure from Wikipedia?  Nice.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at something called "aliasing". `sin` is a periodic function with a period of 2*pi (because it's in radian, not in degrees). In some of your plots your "x-values" (which you don't really plot, which is not so good) are further apart than half a period.

Take a look at the following plots:

```
figure;
hold all;
plot(int2, sin(int2), 'o-');
plot(int1, sin(int1), 'o-');


figure;
hold all;
plot(50*int2, sin(50*int2), 'o-');
plot(50*int1, sin(50*int1), 'o-');
```

You'll see that in both figures, the points of `int2` coincide with points of `int1`. In the second plot, however, linear interpolation between the few points of int1 paints a sine-wave that is not really there.